# High Availibility Failover

Tags: ubuntu, high-availability, failover

What application or solution would i look for for having a server failover/high availibility.

Lets say i have Server 1/Server 2

I want Server 1 to be running an application for example lets say voip solution or some other application. How can i make it so that Server 2 is a complete clone with all the data synced so that in the event Server 1 fails Server 2 kicks in.

I saw there are some solutions like heartbeat with drbd but im not sure if this is what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Actually DRBD is acting like a network level RAID-1 device, It usees haertbeat to detect the other node (active-node) is running or not, if it is not running that will takeover it's IP address and resources,and act like the active node.Basically it uses floating ip address, floating ip address will be on the active node, if the active node fails, that floating IP will be transffered to the passive node. And mount the disk."floating disk"

You can setup a HA based cluster with DRBD. it is not hard to configure.

Comment: Well what i want to do is have Server 2 look just like Server 1. Is that possible? So in the event server 1 fails server 2 kicks in with all the same stuff server 1 had,logs,databses, ect everything.

Comment: That is the main purpose of drbd

Comment: Yup but how do i set it up so that the entire system syncs?

Comment: I jsut get confused when it says to sync a certain partition. Do i install applications to the other partition or how does it work? Thats my confusion.

Comment: It is a floating disk.you need to configure a shared partition on both servers.drbd will mount it when it detects the heartbeat failure.

Comment: How do I install software to this floating disk? Like if I do apt-get install blah. Won't it install to the main partition?

Maybe I'm not getting the concept